# SecureSocial doesn't save the user session, and therefore cannot get past the login screen

Tags: session, playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I'm running Play 2.2.3 with SecureSocial, and it redirects to /account once the user has logged in. However, the session cookie doesn't get saved and I get redirected back to the login screen, despite the following trace:

> [debug] application - [securesocial] user logged in : [SocialUser(IdentityId(nul
>      l,null),null,null,null,Some(anemail@email.com),None,AuthenticationMethod(userP
>      assword),null,null,Some(PasswordInfo(bcrypt,$2a$10$Fv0vIkKQzP4xTdCohQjBkOGgW5KhM
>      L7JtSTTJH3Omdni8288cUrpi,None)))]
>
> [debug] application - [securesocial] anonymous user trying to access : /welcome
>
> [debug] application - [securesocial] calling deleteExpiredTokens()

This indicates that a login has succeeded, but it's not being persisted. Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Did you provide an implementation of UserService, and also add a path to it in your play.plugins file?

Comment: I did, through Debugging I know that the UserService returns a correct Identity, but this is somehow lost.

Comment: It is strange that the fields for IdentityId in the log are null.  If you verified that the UserService returns a correct Identity check if the cookie is being sent back in the response after login.  If it is being sent, then this could be a bug in your UserService.find method implementation. SecureSocial tries to map the id in the cookie to a user in your DB.  If that fails then the request is considered anonymous.

Comment: I also experienced the behaviour described in the original post. I tracked the problem down in the end to a cookie issue. I had set the config attrib "securesocial.cookie.domain" to a wild card domain and then tried to access the site via localhost!